# Remove an Item from Array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I am pulling tables from a database and I'm trying to keep the userdata table from being included in the array that is eventually sent to my application.  I've tried using array_diff and unset, but I haven't had any luck with it.  As tables can be added, the userdata one won't always be in the same position.

The array when I check on JSONlint.com appears like this:

```
[{"table_name": "OSA"
}, {
    "table_name": "OSB"
}, {
    "table_name": "userdata"
}]
```

code in PHP file:

```
    $tables = array();

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    array_push($tables, array("table_name"=>$row[0]));

    }

    $remove= array({"table_name": "userdata"});
    $result = array_diff($tables, $remove);

    echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: How did you call unset?

Comment: Since the data comes from a database, it should be possible to change the query so it does not retrieve the `table_name` key.

Comment: this PHP code should fail, because you try to declare an associative array as you would do with a dict in python or an object in JS. In PHP arrays are (more or less) all the same. Change line 8 to `$remove= array(array("table_name" => "userdata"));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optimal way would probably be to exclude it in the query:

```
SELECT column FROM table WHERE column <> 'userdata'
```

Or, just don't add it to the array:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if($row[0] != 'userdata') {
        $tables[] = array('table_name' => $row[0]);
    }
}
```

Your `array_push` should work fine but I prefer the above.

But to answer the `unset` question.  Just get the `table_data` column values, search for `userdata` and `unset` that key:

```
unset($tables[array_search('userdata', array_column($tables, 'table_name'))]);
```

Comment: Thank you!  The unset worked for me,  I failed to include the array_column when I was trying it.  The while loop generated an error for me when I ran it through JSONLint.com, it came up stating too many open connections.